# Moving a point on a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I have the general equation of a plane in the form $ax+by+cz+d=0$. I also have it's normal and the coordinates of a point that lies on the plane ($E$). I want to calculate the coordinates of a new point on this plane ($F$) which lies on the circumference of a circle with its origin in $E$ at radius $r$, angle $α$.

Image representation:

[image]

I know of the formula for calculating a point on the circumference of a circle

$$x = cx + r \cos(a)$$
$$y = cy + r \sin(a)$$

but not sure how that can be adapted for a particular plane instead of the standard XYZ axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "angle $\alpha$"? In the $xy$ plane, $\alpha$ would be the angle with the $x$-axis, but there is no $$-axis in this plane.

Comment: @BenGrossmann in my case I assume any set of orthogonal vectors could be assigned  as the axes of my plane. I want to calculate points spanning across the entire circumference of the circle (say every 1 degree) so the orientation of the axes isn't relevant for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to parameterize this circle is as follows. Let $n$ denote a normal vector to the plane (for instance, $n = (a,b,c)$).

1. Find a non-zero vector $v = (v_x,v_y,v_z)$ parallel to the plane (i.e. perpendicular to the plane's normal vector). Let $\hat v$ denote the normalized vector $\hat v = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$.
2. Compute the cross-product $w = n \times v$. $w = (w_x,w_y,w_z)$ is a vector in the plane that is orthogonal to $v$. Let $\hat w$ denote the normalized vector $\hat w = \frac w{\|w\|}$.
3. The circle of radius $r$, within the given plane, centered at point $E:(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ can be parameterized with the following equation:
   $$
   (x,y,z) = (x_0,y_0,z_0) + r\cos \alpha( \hat v_x,\hat v_y,\hat v_z) + r\sin \alpha(\hat w_x,\hat w_y,\hat w_z).
   $$

$\alpha$ denotes the angle within the plane between the vectors $v$ and $\vec{EF}$.

Comment: So for example, the formula for calculating x would be:
x = x0 + +r*cosα(v^x)+sinα(w^x)  ?

Comment: We would have $x = x_0 + r \hat v_x\cos \alpha + r \hat w_x \sin \alpha$. I suspect that this is what you were trying to write but it's not totally clear.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to write. Thank you for the clarification.